# Preloader fade out and content fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is easy fix. I need that my preloader fade out slowly. I tried with css animation but didn't work. Can somebody tell me how should i do that in javascript ? As you can see in example, the transition is very rough. I don't want that.

```
<script> <!--Preloader-->
var myVar;

function preloader() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEWaPX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following changes into your codes.

```
#preloader {
  transition:1s ease;
}

#wrapper {
  opacity:0;/*Remove display and hide opacity*/
 }

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("preloader").style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

transition doent work with display block and none..

use

```
var myVar;

function preloader() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("preloader").style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

and

```
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color:black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color:white;
  transition: 0.5s all linear
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate display: none itself, what you can do is animate opacity: 0 for example.

You'll add display: block, while opacity is still 0. After that add opacity: 1 and animate that

Answer (score 1):

Try this example may helps you.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#loader-image").fadeIn(500, function() {
    $("#loader-image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(".loader-container").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        alert("loaded!");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.loader-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
#loader-image {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="loader-container">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Image" id="loader-image" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS transition.
Change your preloader styles to:

```
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color:black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color:white;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1; // Add opacity
  transition: 1s opacity ease-in; // Add transition
}
```

Add styles for the hidden class:

```
#preloader.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then when you call `showPage()`

```
function showPage() {
      // Add the newly defined hidden class to the preloader element
      document.getElementById("preloader").classList.add('hidden');
}
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbeqro) is a working example.